# 502 error with wordpress:fpm using jwilder/nginx-proxy

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

> **TL;DR**
>   why this [wordpress:latest Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/c3c8a37506b1bd79ae05e547faa3d31c84620051/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile) is ok with [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)   but this one not [wordpress:fpm Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/c3c8a37506b1bd79ae05e547faa3d31c84620051/php5.6/fpm/Dockerfile) ? And how can I use a `wordpress:fpm` image with `nginx-proxy`

Hi,

I successfully use nginx-proxy with some wordpress container.  for example this `docker-compose.yml` works perfectly :

```
db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  volumes:
    - /home/stack/my_domain/bdd:/var/lib/mysql

wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=my_domain.fr,www.my_domain.fr
    - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=www.my_domain.fr
    - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=contact@my_domain.fr
  env_file:
    - ./env

  volumes:
    - /home/stack/my_domain/wordpress:/var/www/html
```

BUT if I use the `wordpress:fpm` image  (instead of an apache based image) I have 502 Bad Gateway error, and this message in the log:

> nginx.1    | 2017/08/14 21:29:51 [error] 347#347: *2447 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.222.20.31, server: www.my_domain.fr, request: "GET /contact/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.17.0.14:80/contact/", host: "www.my_domain.fr", referrer: "https://www.my_domain.fr/"

and this message :

> root@9408854fae4b:/etc/nginx/conf.d# nginx -s reload
>   2017/08/14 21:37:35 [emerg] 671#671: invalid number of arguments in "upstream" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:53
>   nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "upstream" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:53

the default.conf at line 53 contains

```
upstream mydomain.fr {
                                ## Can be connect with "bridge" network
                        # my_domain_wordpress_1
                        server 172.17.0.14:9000;
}
```

other domain have server `172.17.0.xx:80;` so I add `port:80` and/or `expose:80` in the docker-compose.yml file. I manage to obtain

```
upstream mydomain.fr {
                                ## Can be connect with "bridge" network
                        # my_domain_wordpress_1
                        server 172.17.0.14:80;
}
```

but with the same 502 error.

Any idea why ?

Regards

Comment: seems close to : https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen/issues/196

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that both of the images are different in their working.

The `wordpress:latest` uses apache on port 80 and responds to requests with the proper PHP script executed. It handles the HTTP protocol.

On the other hand `wordpress:fpm` uses PHP-FPM, which is a Fast CGI server, it is not expecting just `proxy_pass` but other nginx parameters like below

```
     location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass http://fpm:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }
```

`nginx-proxy` image just checks which containers are launched with a `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variables, check its exposed ports and then just creates a proxy pass template. What you need is a different template for this. This can be done using a per-host configuration.

> **Per-VIRTUAL_HOST**
>
> To add settings on a per-VIRTUAL_HOST basis, add your configuration file under /etc/nginx/vhost.d. Unlike in the proxy-wide case, which allows multiple config files with any name ending in .conf, the per-VIRTUAL_HOST file must be named exactly after the VIRTUAL_HOST.
>
> In order to allow virtual hosts to be dynamically configured as backends are added and removed, it makes the most sense to mount an external directory as /etc/nginx/vhost.d as opposed to using derived images or mounting individual configuration files.
>
> For example, if you have a virtual host named app.example.com, you could provide a custom configuration for that host as follows:
>
> $ docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /path/to/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
> $ { echo 'server_tokens off;'; echo 'client_max_body_size 100m;'; } > /path/to/vhost.d/app.example.com

Follow the below URL for more details

https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#per-virtual_host